# Nullable type producing warnings since project has enabled nullable reference types

Tags: c#, nullable, nullable-reference-types

I only get the warnings after I enable nullable reference types, but the specific example is actually the good old `Nullable<T>` type:

```
var nullableItems = new List<int?>();

var actualNonNullValues = nullableItems.Where(x => x.HasValue)
                                       .Select(x => x.Value)
                                       .ToList();
```

So I sort out all the nulls and only want the actual non-null items. However, the part `.Select(x => x.Value)` will give me a compiler warning about `x` maybe being null here. Logically, it is not, but for the compiler, the type has not yet changed and it's still a `int?`.

I know I can tell the compiler to shut up by just applying an `!` to the `x`, but it seems like I cheated. In other languages I use, having to fall back onto this is considered bad practice and means you did something wrong.

What are my other options? Can I do better than just use an `!` here?

Comment: You don't have to use `!`, but it's not going to be "better". Sometimes `!` is just something that you should use. Otherwise it would have been removed from the language.

Comment: What's `id`? I don't see that in the code. Remember that it's nullable *reference* types, while `int?` is a nullable value type, so the warning is not related to the `int?` part.

Comment: @madreflection Sorry, I renamed the example. x was named id in my actual code. I edited my post. and the warning is definetely about a Nullable<T> item. nullable reference types do not have the properties .HasValue and .Value.

Comment: The compiler doesn't evaluate your predicate, it can't know if it's an int? or an int that the Where is returning.

Comment: @AbdelkrimBournane Because `int?.Value` is an `int`, and the deduced type of `actualNonNullValues` is correctly `List<int>`, not `List<int?>`.

Comment: do you want only want, actual non-null items?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `Select(x => x.Value)`, `x` is of type `int?` so compiler promptly warns you that calling `.Value` on that type might throw.

This does not make much sense since you already checked for nullability in the `.Where(x => x.HasValue)`. Unfortunately, C# compiler does not currently understand that the `Select` will receive only non-null values as its context has no understanding of the `Where` method semantics.

Only option you have is `!` as it says "I know what I'm doing here."

There is a language issue tracking this: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/3951